# What's the measure of the $\angle BAC$ in the triangle below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the right triangle $ABC$, right at $B$, the corner $AF$ is drawn such that $AB = FC$ and $\angle ACB = 2 \angle BAF$. Calculate $\angle BAC$.

My progress:

[image]

$\triangle ABF: cos(\frac{C}{2}) = \frac{x}{AF}\\
AF^2 = x^2+BF^2\\
\triangle AFC: Law ~of~ cosines:\\
AF^2 = x^2+AC^2-2.x.AC.cosC\\
\triangle ABC:\\
cos C = \frac{BC}{AC} =\frac{x+BC}{AC}\\
x^2+(x+BF)^2 = AC^2\\
Th.Stewart \triangle ABC:\\
AC^2.BF+x^3=AF^2BC+BC.x.BF$

...??

Comment: Can you tell the origin of all the problems you ask, which often have the same "flavour" ? Do they come from a same book ?

Comment: More to the point, will you tell the origin?

Comment: @JeanMarie  - "Problemas de Geometria y Como Resolverlos - I Edição "- It's a Peruvian book that I have...

Comment: Thanks for this hispano-portuguese reference. As I understand from the title they give methods of solutions  in this book ? But not sufficient, isn't it ?

Comment: @JeanMarie There is no English version for this book...so I put the original title (in Spanish). - In English it would be Problems of Geometry and How to Solve Them -There is a lot of theory and many solved exercises, all solved exclusively by geometry. As geometry is very developed in Peru, it is a very complete book.  Exercises with a degree of difficulty above average

Comment: Thanks for these precisions. As geometry under its different forms is my favorite subject, I was asking myself why you were working on these (surely interesting) problems but not on the many other facets of geometry ? For example conic curves, analytic geometry, projective geometry, geometry involving complex numbers, etc ?

Comment: @JeanMarie  You're welcome..I like plane geometry and everything I learn here I pass on to another forum where there are people who also have this same interest, because I think knowledge should be shared. And I owe a lot of gratitude to my colleagues MathLover and ACB who are always passing on their knowledge.

Comment: I also believe strongly in sharing knowledge.

Comment: @JeanMarie  I am glad that somehow my doubts are helping others. The interesting thing about the book is that it doesn't use trigonometry...all the exercises are solved by geometry and mainly by auxiliary constructions...that is what is fascinating...how they can visualize these constructions...

Comment: It is true that "pure geometry methods" (à la Euclides) can be fascinating. But experience shows that enlarging the spectrum of methods (indeed for 2D plane geometry using trigonometry, and as well analytic geometry, barycentric coordinates, etc.) 1) aleviates the difficulties 2) provides a source of richness, like learning about different cultures, for a human comparison.

Comment: I completely agree but I just want to respect the essence of the book and keep geometry as the basis of the resolutions

Comment: @petaarantes I just downloaded pdf of the book, it looks amazing!

Comment: @Soheil  Yes...but be careful because it is a book with many wrong answers to the exercises and many poorly drawn pictures where you don't know where the author has put the dots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a construction that makes things simple. Extend $CB$ such that $BE = BF = y$

[image]

Now $ \displaystyle \angle BAE = \frac{\angle C}{2} \implies \angle CAE = 90^0 - \frac{\angle C}{2}$

And we notice that $\triangle ACE$ is isosceles so $AC = x + 2y$

Applying Pythagoras in $\triangle ABC$,

$(x+2y)^2 = x^2 + (x+y)^2$

$4y^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2xy = (x-y)^2$

That leads to $x = 3y$ and sides of $\triangle ABC$ are in the ratio $3:4:5$

Answer (score 3):

If $y=BF$ and $t=\tan\frac{C}{2}=\frac{y}{x}$, then $\tan C=\frac{x}{y+x}=\frac{1}{1+t}$

Also $\tan{C}=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}$ from the double angle formula. It follows that:

$$\frac{2t}{1-t^2}=\frac{1}{1+t}$$

And you cand find $t=\frac{1}{3}$ by solving this equation. It follows that $\tan C=\frac{3}{4}$, $\tan\angle BAC=\frac{4}{3}$, and finally $\angle BAC=\arctan\frac{4}{3}$

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: This is a method for reference, it approximates your angle answer:

We know that:

$\tan(\frac{c}{2}) = \frac{BF}{x}$

$\tan(90-c) = \frac{x+BF}{x} = 1 + \frac{BF}{x} = 1+\tan(\frac{c}{2})$

Using the relation between sine, cosine and tangent:

$\frac{\cos(c)}{\sin(c)}$ = $1+\frac{\sin(\frac{c}{2})}{\cos(\frac{c}{2})}$

Then using the half-angle formulae:

$\frac{\cos(c)}{\sin(c)}$ = $1\pm\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos(c)}{2}}}{\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(c)}{2}}}$

$\frac{\cos(c)}{\sin(c)}$ = $1+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos^2(c)}{4}}}{\frac{1+\cos(c)}{2}}$

Using Pythagorean-Trig identity:

$\frac{\cos(c)}{\sin(c)}$ = 1+$\frac{\sin(c)}{\cos(c)+1}$

$\cos^2(c)+\cos(c)$=$\sin^2(c) +\sin(c)\cos(c)+\sin(c)$

$\cos(2c)+\cos(c)-\sin(c)\cos(c)-\sin(c)=0$

$2\cos(2c)+2\cos(c)-\sin(2c)-2\sin(c)=0$

Because $c$ is real:

$(\cos(\frac{c}{2}))(-\sin(c)+2\cos(c)-1)=0$

$\sin(c)=2\cos(c)-1$

$\sqrt{1-\cos^2(c)} = 2\cos(c)-1$

$4\cos^2(c)-4\cos(c)+1=1-\cos^2(c)$

$(\cos(c))(5\cos(c)-4) = 0$

--> $\cos(c)=\frac{4}{5}$, given that $0<c<90$

$c \approx 37^o$

$180^o - 37^o - 90^o = 53^o$

Comment: The point is do you understand my solution? Seems like I confused you

Comment: i understand but if cosC = $\frac{4}{5}$ $, \angle C \approx 37^o$ and not $64^o$

Comment: Yeah my bad, I will correct